# filezilla sftp FATAL ERROR: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, sftp

trying to connect to the server with sftp

home -> server1(x,x,x,x) -> server2(192.168.0.10)

```
Status:         Connecting to 192.168.0.10...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=9
Command:    proxy 1 "x,x,x,x" 22 "kim" "****"
Command:    keyfile "/Users/kim/.ssh/id_rsa"
Command:    open "jake@192.168.0.10" 22
Error:          FATAL ERROR: Connection reset by peer
Error:          Could not connect to server
```

Comment: Are you sure the SSH service is running on 192.168.0.10 and listening at port 22? *Connection reset by peer* indicates it is not.

Comment: By the way, an internet search for *sftp "connection reset by peer"* would have given you plenty of results telling you that there is no SSH service listening at the remote address, such as https://superuser.com/questions/1129510/sftp-connection-reset-by-peer.